# Angular Material md-select multiple align horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) [md-select](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) with the `multiple` flag

```
<div layout="row"
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Pick State</label>
    <md-select multiple flex ng-model="main.selectedData.State">
      <md-option ng-repeat="(key, value) in main.State" value="{{value.value}}">
        {{value.display}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

When I select my multiple options, everything works as expected on the controller end, but in the view my options stack vertically.

[image]

I would like to list them horizontally. So instead of:

```
AR,
CA
```

I would get:

```
AR, CA
```

I think the problem is that the rendered DOM comes out like this:

```
<md-select-value class="md-select-value" id="select_value_label_1">
  <span>
    <div class="md-container">
      <div class="md-icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-text ng-binding">
        AR
    </div>
    ,
    <div class="md-container">
      <div class="md-icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-text ng-binding">
        CA
    </div>
  </span>
  <span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</md-select-value>
```

So if I try to add my own CSS to `float: left` or something like that, I get this:

[image]

I have reported this [on Github as well](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8726), but I'm not sure they consider it a bug, so I am trying to find a work around short of rewriting or altering the module itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css:

```
    ._md-container{
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

http://codepen.io/nsuthar0914/pen/pbgxWo

Comment: It looks like they accepted a PR to fix this, but it's not yet released, but this is still a good fix.

Comment: how to make icons(checkbox) visible. I using am google font icons